# "StructureMapConfigurationException was caught" Could not find an Instance named 'cert5' for plugintype

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap, objectfactory

my controller class

```
 IPaymentProcessor _paymentProcessor = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IPaymentProcessor>("cert5");
```

my IoC class

```
   x.For<IX509Cert>().Use<X509Cert>().Ctor<string>().Is(Settings.GetCreditCardCertFile(5)).Named("cert5");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple credit card cert files it may be a better option to not use the IoC container. You can use an instance of the IPaymentprocesssor inside your controller directly instead.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though.